# PouchDB code won't work without adding attachment

Tags: javascript, cordova, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm building an app to store information items. Currently there are 3 input fields (Title, description and fileinput).

When I fill in all three fields and call the addItem() function, it works. But when I leave the input field empty, the function doesn't add it to the database.

Is there a way to tell that the file input field is not required?

My javascript code:

```
function addItem() {

    //get file
    var inputFile = document.querySelector('#inputFile');
    var getFile = inputFile.files[0];

    //get info
    var title = document.getElementById('itemTitle').value;
    var desc = document.getElementById('itemDesc').value;

    //add
    locallp.put({
    _id: new Date().toISOString(),
    title: title,
    description: desc,
    _attachments: {
        "file": {
            content_type: getFile.type,
            data: getFile
        }
    } 
    }).then(function(){
      console.log("Added to the database");
        location.href = "menu.html";  
    }).catch(function(err){
       console.log(err);
    });
}
```

some extra info, I'm using Cordova to build the app. My database is PouchDB and connected via couchperuser to a CouchDB server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be surprised that your second line (`inputFile.files[0]`) even works if you don't provide a file.  In any case, I'm sure the `getFile.type` method call will fail if there's no file.

You need some logic in this method so that it does two different things based on whether there's a file supplied or not.  If there is one then it does what you have, if there isn't then it doesn't try adding the `_attachments` and probably skips the whole setting of `getFile` too.

Comment: thank you. just curious if there is an option within pouch or something. I shall try using two different put() functions.

Comment: It's nothing to do with PouchDB, code like `getFile.type` just can never work if `getFile` is `null`.